# MySQL - Get users who have NO orders in current month but don have in previous, in one request

Tags: mysql

I need to get users count, grouped by user type (A,B,C) and every month (that exist in db) in current year - only for users who don't have paid orders (with total > 0) in every month (every row returned by SQL), but have orders (with total > 0) in any previous months (in any year, not just current). In other words this is inactive users, who placed some paid order before, but don't placed any new orders in current SQL request row month returned.

What I expect to get in results (values are just examples):

```
label   user_type   data
 Nov    B           2
 Nov    A           1
 Nov    C           3
 Dec    C           1
 .... other months
```

This means that in December there are 5 users with user type A and 3 users with user type B and 0 users with user type C, who DON'T placed orders in December 2021, but placed orders sometime before December in any year.

Sample DB (two tables - users and orders) with SQL that show number users, by every user type, in every month, who placed orders in this month. Instead of just this simple results, I need to get users counts that DON'T placed orders in this month, but placed paid orders somewhere before.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4c4fadf67bcdc7cc3443f46c387173df

I need SQL that will work with MySQL 5.7

Comment: Is there only going to be three types?

Comment: @SalmanA No, this is just example. This types should be in GROUP BY, so it's count should not matter.

Comment: @Luuk this solution require creation of additional tables with special structure, this is not what I need.

Comment: Split your SQL statements on DBFIDDLE into 1 statement per block, then you will notice an error when inserting data into table `orders`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5d1f192c1b8050690dcf12a9c794caa8

Comment: @Luuk I am not sure how to add date properly in dbfiddle :(

Comment: The question title looks opposite of the description. If description is correct, I am assuming you want 12 rows... one for each month in 2021. Right?

Comment: @SalmanA thanks, fixed title. Yes, I need data for every month, but only if this month exists will be fine (so if no any data in December for all of user types this is not a problem if this will not be included in results. So group by MONTH YEAR should work fine, without data for empty months that are not in db.

Comment: @Dmitry: see this changed dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0a1c2897684c0ec48fde4ce3a3a0e5cc

Comment: Pretty common request, and nobody know how to get this done ?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query to generate counts for all months x user type

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURDATE()), months.mm, '01')), "%b") as label, 
  users.user_type, 
  SUM(
    EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM orders
     WHERE orders.user_id = users.userid
     AND orders.`date` < DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURDATE()), months.mm, '01'))
    ) AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM orders
     WHERE orders.user_id = users.userid
     AND orders.`date` BETWEEN DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURDATE()), months.mm, '01')) AND LAST_DAY(DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURDATE()), months.mm, '01')))
    )
  ) counts
FROM (
 SELECT '01' mm
 UNION SELECT '02' UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION SELECT '05' 
 UNION SELECT '06' UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08' UNION SELECT '09' 
 UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11' UNION SELECT '12'
) months
CROSS JOIN users
GROUP BY months.mm, users.user_type
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c798cb2a38f4622a56c677d047a78ece)

Comment: As I see this is for current year. If I need another year I should replace ALL "YEAR(CURDATE())" to "2020" for example?

Comment: As I see replacing with 2021 does not work. Also since you have CURDATE() everywhere - I assume your SQL does not see orders from previous years? So if user placed orders in 2019 for ex. your code does not see this (but should see). Also only orders with 'total' > 0 should be counted as placed order. So if user placed order in Nov 2019 and don't placed orders after - he will be counted as inactive for all months next to Nov 2019 - e.g. Dec 2019, Jan 2020, ... Feb 2021, etc. If user placed orders with total = 0 (free trial) he does not counted anywhere at all (like he never placed order)

Comment: `YEAR(CURDATE())` is `2021`, clause `AND orders.date < DATE(CONCAT ...` checks orders before the given month including previous years.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fe174285778b23ad19f91600f693f430

Comment: Yes, but what If I need to check 2020 or 2019? Where and how I should replace YEAR(CURDATE()) to 2019?

Comment: In the last comment I add another link with constant `2021`, you can replace it with other years, a number of places to replace.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fe174285778b23ad19f91600f693f430

Answer (score 0):

Test this query if it fits your needs

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(o.date, "%b") as label,
UPPER(u.user_type) as user_type,
COUNT(distinct o.user_id) as data FROM orders o 
JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.userid 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(o.date, "%Y") = "2021"
AND o.user_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT o1.user_id FROM orders o1 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(o1.date, "%b") = DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%b") AND YEAR(o1.date) = YEAR(now()) )
AND o.user_id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT o1.user_id FROM orders o1 WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(o1.date, "%c") < DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%c") OR YEAR(o1.date) < YEAR(now())))

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(o.date, "%Y %b"), 
u.user_type HAVING SUM(o.total) > 0 ORDER BY o.date ASC
```

**EDIT**
The query below returns every month of the year

```
SELECT months.MONTH as label,
ifnull(UPPER(u.user_type), '-') as user_type,
COUNT(distinct o.user_id) as data 
FROM (
                      SELECT 1 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 2 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 3 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 4 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 5 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 6 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 7 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 8 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 9 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH
            ) as months

LEFT JOIN orders o 
 ON DATE_FORMAT(o.date, "%c") = months.MONTH 
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.userid
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(o.date, "%Y") = "2021" OR o.date IS NULL)
AND ( 
        (
        NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT DISTINCT o1.user_id 
                FROM orders o1 
                    WHERE 
                    DATE_FORMAT(o1.date, "%b") = DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%b") 
                    AND YEAR(o1.date) = YEAR(now())
                    AND  o1.user_id = o.user_id
            )
        AND EXISTS
            (SELECT DISTINCT o1.user_id 
                FROM orders o1 
                    WHERE 
                    (DATE_FORMAT(o1.date, "%c") < DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%c") OR YEAR(o1.date) < YEAR(now())) AND  o1.user_id = o.user_id
            )
        ) 
        OR o.user_id IS null OR u.userid IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY months.MONTH, u.user_type ORDER BY months.MONTH ASC
```

Comment: As I understand within "IN" you add users who have order placed before current numeric month (for ex. <11 month for november), however in this case users who placed orders in another years (for ex. in 12 month in December 2020 or December 2019, etc) will be ignored and this will be incorrect.

Comment: For ex. user placed order in 12.2019 (december 2019) but don't placed order in current month (for ex. in 11.2021, November). You will check for users who placed orders NOT IN "Nov" and add users who placed orders IN <11 month. In this case user with order from 12.2019 (any year and 12 month) will not be counted, but this is not correct.

Comment: and I think this overall will not work correct between all looped months in GROUP BY. Because you are checking now() - current date month. Not a date in SQL groyp by iteration (So this will be list of months in year, but you are checking only current month, December in our case).

Comment: I am editing the answer to support the first two comments

Comment: In other words instead of now() here should be variable that store current month, related for current row month "label" (in results as table). But I am not sure if construction like this technically possible in MySQL. For ex. if we currently at row for July 2021 - we need to check that counted users have orders <July 2021 and don't have orders in July 2021 - but your SQL check only current month (December 2021), not Jan,Feb,Mar, etc.., Dec - current iterated month within GROUP BY.

Comment: Your last comment confused me a little bit. If you want to test another date you can manually replace the now(). Or programmaticaly with a variable. Or you can create a function that takes as parameter the date you want to test. Did i missed something?

Comment: Your current SQL will show how many users don't have new orders placed in TODAY's month (December if we talking today), in every month when somebody placed orders. But I need to see how many users don't have new orders in EVERY (not just today) month exactly for entire one year. For ex. some user placed order in Jan 2021, then he placed order in July 2021, and then he don't placed more orders. This means this user will BE counted in all months (Feb, Mar, Apr, Jun, Aug, Sep, Nov, Dec) exclude Jan and July (because he placed orders in this month).

Comment: In other words - this counts in table is a users count who DON'T placed orders this months (inactive users), but they was active somewhere before.

Comment: So I need to know inactive users count for EVERY month in selected year (in our case 2021).

Comment: If we imagine that only this one test user exist (that I mentioned) we should get results: Jan = 0, Feb = 1, Mar = 1, Apr = 1, Jun = 1, Jul = 0, Aug = 1, Sep = 1, Nov = 1, Dec = 1

Comment: 1 - means that 1 user who was active previous to this specific month (not NOW) does not placed order in this month (0 users was inactive in Jan - because our one test user PLACED order in Jan, then 1 was inactive in Feb - because our user placed order in Jan, but don't placed order in Feb - so he INACTIVE user FOR FEBRUARY - but this does not mean that he will be inactive for all next months -we see that he was ACTIVE in July later).

Comment: I mean that same user can be inactive in Jan (he will be counted as +1 user), then active in other month(s) (he will not be counted for this month), and then inactive in some other month(s) again within year.

Comment: User placed order in a month - he ACTIVE in THIS month (when he placed order). User does not placed order in a month - he INACTIVE in THIS month (when he does not placed order).

Comment: In other words in DATE_FORMAT(o1.date, "%b") = DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%b") instead of now() we need to have some kind of dynamic variable that related to month that are currently in list of months found for "group by" (lists of months when we have users who don't placed orders in this months).

Comment: I think you code will works fine if I will use it in FOREACH loop (in web app) and will make 12 SQL requests (for every month) with iterated month instead of now(). But I am still curious if this is possible to get this results in PURE SQL in one request (instead of 12). Iterate your request within 12 months and get results in one request.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a similar approach to VeteranSlayer but it starts with the cross join between months and users followed by the left join to orders. It also uses ranges for the date comparisons instead of the functions. It may perform really badly but it should give the correct result -

```sql
SELECT
    months.month AS `label`,
    u.user_type,
    COUNT(u.userid) AS `data`
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jan' `month`, '2021-01-01' month_start, '2021-01-31' month_end UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Feb', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mar', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Apr', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jun', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jul', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aug', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sep', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Oct', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nov', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dec', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'
) months
INNER JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON o.date BETWEEN months.month_start AND months.month_end
    AND o.user_id = u.userid
WHERE o.user_id IS NULL
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT o1.user_id 
    FROM orders o1 
    WHERE o1.date < months.month_start
    AND  o1.user_id = u.userid
)
GROUP BY months.month, u.user_type
ORDER BY months.month_start ASC, u.user_type ASC;
```

**EDIT**

The performance of these queries varies dramatically based on the scale of the dataset, the distribution of data and the indices.  I have done some tests with many different index variations and the following test datasets. Note the random data created in the two tables can lead to wildly different performance. The `dummy` table referenced in the SELECTs of the INSERTs is just a random table with 1M rows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
    KEY `IDX_user_type` (`user_type`)
);

INSERT INTO users (user_type)
SELECT 
    CASE (FLOOR(RAND() * 3) + 1) WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END AS `user_type`
FROM dummy
LIMIT 1000;


CREATE TABLE orders (
    `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_id` int,
    `date` DATE,
    `total` DECIMAL(6,2),
    KEY `IDX_user_id_date` (`user_id`,`date`)
);

INSERT INTO orders (user_id, date, total)
SELECT
     (FLOOR(RAND() * 1000) + 1) AS `user_id`,
     ('2020-01-01' + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 685) + 1 DAY) AS `date`,
     ( (FLOOR(RAND() * 10) + 1) * 5) AS `total`
FROM dummy
LIMIT 100000;
```

The most significant performance difference across the queries came from adding -

```
KEY `IDX_user_id_date` (`user_id`,`date`)
```

and adding the user_type index gave a small but consistent improvement -

```
KEY `IDX_user_type` (`user_type`)
```

ProGu's query executed consistently with an average time of 1.466 sec. And my query was similarly consistent at 0.922 sec. Your mileage will vary!

I haven't included time's for VeteranSlayer's query as it returned radically different results.

**EDIT 2**

Repopulated the two tables with 50k users and 1M orders

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE orders;
TRUNCATE TABLE users;

INSERT INTO users (user_type)
SELECT 
    CASE (FLOOR(RAND() * 3) + 1) WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END AS `user_type`
FROM  (SELECT 1 FROM dummy LIMIT 50000) t;

INSERT INTO orders (user_id, date, total)
SELECT
     (FLOOR(RAND() * 50000) + 1),
     TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-01-01', '2021-12-13')), '2016-01-01'),
     ((FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 1) * 5)
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dummy LIMIT 1000000) t
ORDER BY date;
```

The resulting distribution of orders, by time and user_id, is quite even which is unlikely to be realistic so this test dataset grossly exacerbates any performance issues, I think.

I was surprised that by using my months table, ProGu's query was significantly faster, dropping from 21.062sec to 9.703sec, and using one less temporary table (two instead of three).

```sql
SELECT 
  months.month as label, 
  users.user_type, 
  SUM(
    EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM orders
     WHERE orders.user_id = users.id
     AND orders.`date` < months.month_start
    ) AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM orders
     WHERE orders.user_id = users.id
     AND orders.`date` BETWEEN months.month_start AND months.month_end
    )
  ) counts
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jan' `month`, '2021-01-01' month_start, '2021-01-31' month_end UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Feb', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mar', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Apr', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jun', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jul', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aug', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sep', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Oct', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nov', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dec', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'
) months
CROSS JOIN users
GROUP BY months.month, users.user_type
ORDER BY months.month_start ASC, users.user_type ASC
```

My query above can be significantly improved by pre grouping the orders data for the current year (your mileage will vary but worth considering) -

```sql
SELECT
    months.month AS `label`,
    u.user_type,
    COUNT(u.id) AS `data`
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jan' `month`, '2021-01-01' month_start, '2021-01-31' month_end UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Feb', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mar', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Apr', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jun', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jul', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aug', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sep', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Oct', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nov', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dec', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'
) months
INNER JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-01') AS `m`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `date` >= '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY `user_id`, `m`
) o
    ON o.m = months.month_start
    AND o.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.user_id IS NULL
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM orders o1 
    WHERE o1.date < months.month_start
    AND  o1.user_id = u.id
)
GROUP BY months.month, u.user_type
ORDER BY months.month_start ASC, u.user_type ASC
```

Execution time dropped from 12.422sec to 6.497sec

And the final test I tried was de-normalising by adding first_order_date to the users table -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `first_order_date` DATE NULL AFTER `user_type`;

UPDATE users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT o.user_id, MIN(date) AS `first_o`, MAX(date) AS `last_o` FROM orders o GROUP BY o.user_id) t ON u.id = t.user_id
SET `u`.`first_order_date` = `t`.`first_o`, `u`.`last_order_date` = `t`.`last_o`;
```

I then modified my query to use this instead of the EXISTS sub-query -

```sql
SELECT
    `months`.`month` AS `label`,
    `u`.`user_type`,
    COUNT(`u`.`id`) AS `data`
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jan' `month`, '2021-01-01' month_start, '2021-01-31' month_end UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Feb', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mar', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Apr', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jun', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jul', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aug', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sep', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Oct', '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nov', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dec', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'
) `months`
INNER JOIN `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-01') AS `m`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `date` >= '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY `user_id`, `m`
) o
    ON `o`.`m` =  `months`.`month_start`
    AND `o`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE `o`.`user_id` IS NULL
AND `u`.`first_order_date` < `months`.`month_start`
GROUP BY `months`.`month`, `u`.`user_type`
ORDER BY `months`.`month_start` ASC, `u`.`user_type` ASC;
```

This returns the same result in 1.447sec.  Obviously, de-normalising like this should be avoided but I included it here as it shows the performance benefit for this one scenario.

Comment: good test. can you also try to remove the composite key `IDX_user_id_date` and add two separate keys for the `user_id` and `date` to have a try.

Comment: @ProGu I tried with the composite key replaced by two separate keys and it totally bombed (client timed out for both queries at 60sec). Then realised a significant flaw in that orders.id and orders.date were not both in sequence so I repopulated orders so that both are in order. Your query - 3.389sec and mine 2.422sec. Reinstated the composite key and still same result as before.

Comment: I duplicated your code in db-fiddle with 10k users, 500k orders, it can't run online, I included command line output in one of my mysql8 server. I think yours and mine are very similar according to execution plan, which one better will be dependent on runtime, index and data set.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afb64840d6a1e29539ceb2657b808e28

Comment: and with composite key https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a548c6bafae18a9bb0e65254cd831dbc

Comment: Interesting! I started playing with this to see how much slower mine would be than yours. I retested with 50k users and 1M orders over 5 years and still getting similar results - Yours: 21.203sec (12,649,870 rows examined, 3 in mem temp tables, 2 full table scans) - Mine: 12.297sec (24,599,870 rows examined, 2 in mem temp tables, 1 full table scan). Clearly performance varies significantly based on distribution of orders across users and time. Just to test, I de-normalised by adding first_order_date to users table and reduced mine to 7.406sec. Might be completely different with OP's data.

Comment: @ProGu Your query was significantly faster with my months table.